# Virtual memory and virtual addressing, where does the process's code section start?

Tags: operating-system, memory-address, virtual-memory

Consider the page table below, the process's code section needs to start at **no less** than what virtual address?

Since the only executable and valid address is `0xf000`, I think it should starts at `0xf000`. However, since the question asked **no less than**, I am struggle between the answer `0xe000` and `0xf000`. Could you help me to clarify that? Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: "No less than" is the same as "greater than or equal to". I assume that might be clearer? "No more than" is the same as "less than or equal to"